# Tips of coding java programs in multicore scenario

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, multicore

There seems to be a lot of fuss about multicore and java. While some people say that java support is not [good enough](http://r-c-r.blogspot.com/2008/03/concurrency-support-in-java7-is-not.html), it definitely seems to be an area to look forward to. There seems to be [many](http://www.sdtimes.com/link/32943) [techniques](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2006/jw-1121-thread.html) to improve performance of concurrent programs.

Any tips/advices about programming in a multi core scenario is appreciated.

Comment: Who thinks this question is not constructive? It is constructive.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look into the new Java concurrency facilities (in the [`java.util.concurrent` package](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)) which have been added in Java 5. It provides functionality that is more high-level than regular `Thread`s which will make it easier (and less error-prone) to write concurrent applications. The [Lesson: Concurrency](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) of [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) would be a good place to start.

So far, I've only used the [`ExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), which allows can produce [thread pools](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html), to which new tasks can be handed off in units of [`Runnable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)s or [`Callable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)s (which can return values after execution as [`Future`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s), and the actual threading code is handled by the `ExecutorService`.

For example, performing some calculation using a thread pool of 2 threads, and getting the result can be as simple as:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

Future f1 = es.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
    public Integer call()
    {
        // Do some processing...
        return someInteger;
    }
});

Future f2 = es.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
    public Integer call()
    {
        // Do some processing...
        return someInteger;
    }
});

Integer firstInteger = f1.get();
Integer secondInteger = f2.get();
```

In the above (untested) code, all I have to worry about is making a couple of `Callable`s and [`submit`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable))ing it to the `ExecutorService` and later on, using the `Future`s to retrieve the result.

The catch is, once the [`get`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) method of the `Future` is called, if the processing isn't complete, the program will stop until the result of the `Future` can be retrieved. So, in this example, even if the result of `f2` is available before `f1`, the program will wait until the result of `f1` is available.

In terms of reading material, on my list of books to purchase soon is [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) by Brian Goetz, which comes up often when concurrency in Java is brought up.

The [Concurrency Utilities](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/concurrency/) page from the Java 5 documentation has more information as well.

Answer (score 8):

The best tip has got to be: *get your synchronization correct!*

This may seem somewhat obvious but an understanding of the [Java Memory Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model) is vital, particularly how **volatile** and **final** fields work, how **synchronized** acts as both a mutex *and* a *memory barrier* and then the new `java.util.concurrent` constructs as well

Answer (score 6):

Always a good tip - if most of your classes are immutable everything becomes so much easier as immutability removes the need to worry about locks from many to few places of concern.

Comment: +1.
I always design classes to be immutable and only make mutable if its needed.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the forthcoming [fork-join framework](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11137.html?ca=drs-). The fork-join framework enables developers to achieve fine-grained parallelism on multicore architectures.

Also you may want to check out JVM based languages like [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) that claim to make multicore parallel programming easier.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Java's own shared-memory approach to concurrency you could also look into [Actor-based concurrency using Scala](http://java.dzone.com/articles/scala-threadless-concurrent) on top of Java, which provides an easier model for concurrent programming.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Brian Goetz's talk [From concurrent to Parallel](http://wiki.parleys.com/display/PARLEYS/Home#talk=24576007;title=From%20Concurrent%20to%20Parallel;slide=1) from Devoxx 2008. Not many tips there, but it gives you an idea where Java concurrency is heading to.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a parallelism patterns library such as [Skandium](http://skandium.niclabs.cl) for Java. Simply choose the parallelism pattern you want and fill in the missing hooks.

Some of the patterns sopported in Skandium are:

- Master-slave: `Farm<P,R>(nested);`
- Pipeline: `Pipe(stage1, stage2);
- For iteration: `For<P,R>(nested, i);`
- Conditional iteration: `While<P,R>(nested, condition);`
- Conditional branching: `If<P,R>(condition, trueCase, falseCase);`
- Map-reduce: `Map<P,R>(split, nested, merge);`
- Map-reduce with different code paths: `Fork<P,R>(split, nested, merge);`
- Recursive divide and conquer: `DaC<P,R>(condition, split, nested, merge);`

All patterns can be nested and combine, so you can have farm inside of a divide and conquer, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best book with practical tips has been [Java Concurrency in Practise](http://jcip.net/). It is a must read for all java programmers, even those who thinks they dont do any concurrent programming, because java has many hidden threading in its various libraries (swing comes to mind, same with servlets).

Answer (score 1):

My tip: Understand the Java Memory Model (since JDK 5 and higher). Most people do not know, that synchronization, volatile, and final have an additional meaning beyond the normal multi-threading scope.

Java is fine for multi-cpu and multi-cores. If you program it right and you invest some brain, you get a highly concurrent server system to utilize 8-cores including a lot of synchronization and so on. We are quite happy with it... JDK6 is better than JDK5 and everything below sucks on multi-cpu machines.